# Print_r is not working with preg_split

Tags: php, arrays, preg-split

I writing a function to search within my database. I wanted to eliminate uneccessary white spaces between words so I used preg_split. I have not used preg split before so I used print_r to see if it did what I was hoping for it to do (elimminate white spaces). Yet when I used print_r I got nothing back on my screen to show the array after I typed words in the search.

```
function search_results($keywords){
    $returned_results = array();
    $where = "";

    $keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $keywords);
    print_r($keywords);

}
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could give me an idea as to what I did wrong, or better tips.

Comment: What output do you get? What is a value of `$keywords`?

Comment: Give me ur sample input string

Comment: The value of the keyword is the input from the search bar @PLB

Comment: Input string was "Drinking      water       now" @PrasathAlbert

Comment: Drinking water now with many spaces in between @Codesen

Comment: when you post the keyword to the search page, have you get the correct value? print the keyword in the search page before split.

Comment: @Octavius Your function is "working" function. The problem is that `$keyword` is not what you expect (it's null or empty string, I think). `var_dump($keywords)` before using `preg_split`

Comment: try my answer below that will solve ur problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tyr this

```
$base_str = "this    is a   string  with multiple    spaces between  some words.            "; 


$start = microtime(1); 
for ($i=0; $i<100000; $i++){ 
    $string = $base_str; 
    while(strpos($string, '  ') !== false) 
    { 
         $string = str_replace('  ', ' ', $string); 
    } 
} 

echo $string;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't get any matches with your regexp, that's why you don't get any array. Try this instead:

```
 $keywords = preg_split("/\\s/", $keywords);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested out your function with `search_results("hi there");` It ran perfectly here on my end, no issues. Here's the results I got as expected:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hi
    [1] => there
)
```

Comment: Perhaps the indata needs to be looked upon then.